# Have to close my query in Microsoft Access 2013 each time I want to run a form

Tags: forms, ms-access-2013

every time I want to run a form that searches through my database and returns results based on certain fields (login name, date, etc.) I must close out of the query if I want to change the search criteria. For example, if I search for login name "John" I get all those results, but if I then want to search for "Jerry" I have to close out of the query with the data first, then re-run the form.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Probably you can solve your problem with a few lines of VBA code. Do you really use MySQL as database? If not, please remove the _mysql_ tag.

Comment: I don't really know much VBA. Is there another simple way to fix the issue?

Comment: Or if there's no way to do that, is there a button command on the form I can add that will refresh the query data?

Comment: I don't know your application, but that seems a way to go. Typically after clicking a button of an access form will execute VBA code.

Comment: Do you know any specific commands that might accomplish this? I looked through them all and couldn't figure out which to use

Comment: It depends on your application. I don't know how you implemented your search form.

Comment: The form pops up as a window and calls on a query called "Results" that is linked to 7 tables. I have a "Search" button that takes the fields in the form and updates the respective columns in the query

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991948/ms-access-how-to-do-a-proper-requery can give you good advice.

Answer (score 1):

--This applies to both **Close** and **Opening** method.

--Same applies to all the object(s) not just the ***query*** but also the ***Form*** etc.

To close a query you can use following code.

```
DoCmd.Close acQuery, "Queryname", acSaveNo
```

To explain it better,

DoCmd.Close is a method

it accepts following parameters.

1. What to close (object type:acQuery, acForm etc)
2. Name of the object (in this case Query name)
3. Action to perform when closing (acSaveYes,acSaveNo,acSavePrompt).

**Remember: Saving is actually saving the object(in this case Query) not the data.
To Avoid Accidental modification of the query.I recommend closing the object without saving (unless required and know what you are doing)**

acSaveYes: is to save the form with out notification. This is not saving the data, this is actually saving the object. So i recommend not doing this unless you want users to modify the query.

acSaveNo: This is close the query without saving.If you have users who would like to just view data and don't modify the query this is useful.

acSavePrompt: This is just prompting to either save the object or not.

*Quick tip: While writing the query, if intellisense works then that means your cold is valid.*

ref:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192860%28v=office.15%29.aspx